# Compiling IPOPT with Cygwin and Intel Parallel Studio

Tags: windows, cygwin, intel-mkl, ipopt, intel-parallel-studio

I am attempting to compile IPOPT 3.13.3 in Windows using Cygwin. I have a copy of Intel Parallel Studio 2019 and am trying to use the Intel compilers as well as Intel MKL from this install. Here's my process:

1. Start the Intel compiler 64-bit command prompt
2. Run Cygwin.bat to start up the cygwin bash terminal. I can confirm then that ifort and icl are on the path and will run
3. Navigate to the ipopt source folder and run `./configure --enable-mscv`

From here it finds the compilers fine and it works until trying to get lapack from MKL:

```
checking for function dsyev_ in /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_sequential_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_core_dll.lib ... no
checking for function dsyev in /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_sequential_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_core_dll.lib ... no
checking for function DSYEV_ in /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_sequential_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_core_dll.lib ... no
checking for function DSYEV in /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_sequential_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/INTELS~1/COMPIL~1.144/windows/mkl/lib/INTEL6~1/mkl_core_dll.lib ... no
```

It then proceeds to check the cygwin packages for blas/lapack (which I don't want to do anyway) but that fails too:

```
checking for lapack.pc and blas.pc... yes
checking for function dsyev_ in -llapack  ... no
checking for function dsyev in -llapack  ... no
checking for function DSYEV_ in -llapack  ... no
checking for function DSYEV in -llapack  ... no
configure: WARNING: lapack.pc and blas.pc present, but could not find dsyev when trying to link with it.
checking for function dsyev_ in -llapack -lblas ... no
checking for function dsyev in -llapack -lblas ... no
checking for function DSYEV_ in -llapack -lblas ... no
checking for function DSYEV in -llapack -lblas ... no
configure: error: Required package LAPACK not found.
```

I've tried adding various combinations of libraries manually with the --with-lapack flag, such as suggested here: [Linking Ipopt with Intel MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038444/linking-ipopt-with-intel-mkl), but I generally get the same result. Here's another command I tried:

```
./configure --enable-msvc --with-lapack=" -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl"
```

And here's the output:

```
checking for function dsyev_ in  -LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl ... no
checking for function dsyev in  -LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl ... no
checking for function DSYEV_ in  -LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl ... no
checking for function DSYEV in  -LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144\windows\mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl ... no
configure: error: Could not find dsyev in Lapack
```

It does concern me that there are spaces in the path to MKL (ugh, Windows!), but I tried copying the libraries to another path and linking against that and it didn't change the result.

I also removed the GNU link.exe from the cygwin directory so that running `link --version` confirms I'm using the Microsoft linker (per the recommendation here: [Installing and using IPopt with Cygwin - or even better alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402301/installing-and-using-ipopt-with-cygwin-or-even-better-alternative#)

My internet research is not yielding any more answers. If anyone has some suggestions on what to do here, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `--enable-msvc` instead of `--enable-mscv`.

Best is to make sure that the MKL libs are found in the library search path. Then configure should just pick them up automatically. Otherwise, try to use DOS-style short paths without spaces for the linker flags (https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/issues/472#issuecomment-842446604).

Also if tests in configure fail, look at the config.log file for details.

There should be no need to remove link.exe. There is a workaround for this in the `compile` script that comes with Ipopt.

PS: I haven't tried cygwin. msys2 works for me.